# MySQL:How do I combine two databases in one database

Tags: mysql, database

i have two databases like this

```
    database 1

    CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

**And**

```
database 2

    CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int,
    PersonID int,
    FOREIGN KEY T1 (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

who can i call  table Persons  from database 1 to table Orders  database 2 (in mysql) without import database

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, if you want to move the tables from database 1 to database 2 then you could export and reimport them. If both are on the same mysql server instance and the user has right for both databases then your could target the databases directly in your query. `SELECT * FROM databse1.A`

Comment: @t.niese look at again to my question i changed it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a table from database 1 in a query on the second database then you just prefix the table name with the name of the database

```
SELECT *.db1persons, *.db2orders FROM db1.Persons as db1persons, db2.Orders as db2orders;
```

Or something similar...

Comment: yes i know this , but i need other method because i want  to use primary key , like relation between two databases

Comment: REFERENCES database1.Persons(PersonID)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query from database 1 to fetch the database 2 any tables --

```
SELECT * FROM database1.Person as P inner join database2.Orders as O on P.PersonID=O.PersonID;
```

I already run the above query from my end, this is working.